# Allow repeat in where clause in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table jobskills which consist of three columns id,job_id,skill_id. Uptil now I was using a query like :

`SELECT job_id FROM jobskills WHERE skill_id='$Data1' OR skill_id='$Data2'`

and so on.
I then take the results and then sort the jobs in descending order to get the job with maximum matches.
So if there is a query like

```
select job_id from jobskill 
where 
skill_id='301' or skill_id='301'
```

I will get only one list. However I want the values in the result to be repeated, that is I want the result for both 301 be displayed.

Comment: where skill_id='301' or skill_id='301' doesn't make any sense, it's just redundant. It'd be better if you can provide some data and the result you want returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the point in repeating the same set of data 2 times however you will need to do `UNION ALL` in this case

```
select job_id from jobskill 
where skill_id='301'
UNION ALL
select job_id from jobskill 
where skill_id='301'
```